# Question on Hausdorff distance between two sets with a common compact subset

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hausdorff-distance

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb R^n$ be two closed and non-empty sets. We define the Hausdorff distance by:

$\delta_H(A,B):=\max \big [ \sup_{X\in B} d(X,A),\sup_{Y\in A} d(Y,B) \big ]$

where $d(X,A):=\inf_{Y\in A} \vert X-Y \vert$

Now let $C:=\{x\in A: dist(x, A^\complement) \ge \theta \gt 0 \}$ and suppose  is compact.

**QUESTION:** If $C \subset B$ then can we claim that $\delta_H(B,A) \le \delta_H(C,A)=\theta$ ?

In my defense, I 'm not very familiar to the Hausdorff distance and all my approach is rather intuitive. I would appreciate if somebody could give me some details on whether this assumption is valid or not.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you would want both $A$ and $B$ to be bounded if you want the Hausdorff distance to actually be a metric (otherwise, the distance might be $\infty$, as the following also illustrates). I'm assuming $A$ compact throughout:

The answer is no. Consider $B=B[0,r]$ (the closed ball of radius $r$. Assume $r>0$ large enough that $A\subseteq B(0,r/2)$. \

Then, $x=r(1,0,0,...0)\in B$ and for any $y\in A,$ we have $||x-y||\geq ||x||-||y||\geq r/2$. Hence, $d(x,A)\geq r/2$ and hence, $\delta_H(A,B)\geq r/2.$

So, making $r$ very large, I can make the distance arbitrarily large, even though *every* compact subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. So if they were also bounded in this case the question is true?

Comment: No. Each of my $B$'s are bounded. I'm saying that if you copy the above argument, you'd find that $\delta_H(\mathbb{R}^n,A)=\infty$. In general if $B$ is unbounded and $A$ is non-empty, then $\delta_H(B,A)=\infty$.

Comment: I was asking about my initial $A,B$ subsets. If I had also the compactness assumption for them

Comment: I'm saying that the Hausdorff distance is only a meaningful quantity if both $A$ and $B$ are compact.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou It's wrong what you're saying about $\delta_H$ being infinite in your first comment. Just consider the x-axis and $\{(x,1) : x\in\mathbb R\}$ in $\mathbb R^2$. Both are infinite, but their Hausdorff distance is one.

Comment: @amsmath Right. If you just read it as is, it does read that I'm implying that the distance between an unbounded and a non-empty set is *always* $\infty$. That's definitely wrong. I can't tell you much more about what was going through my head on this september day more than a year ago.

Comment: The moral that 'for Hausdorff distance to generically make sense, you'd need boundedness' remains true, though.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Thanks for your response. Actually, I only stumbled over this post since I have a question myself concerning the Hausdorff metric. If you wanna have a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4038893/continuity-with-respect-to-hausdorff-metric-also-with-intersection