# Continuity with respect to Hausdorff metric, also with intersection?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hausdorff-distance

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space and let $v\in H$, $\|v\|=1$. Now, consider the affine subspaces $A(t) := tv + v^\perp$ of codimension $1$, $t\in\mathbb R$. Obviously
$$
d_H(A(t),A(s)) = |t-s|
$$
for all $t,s\in\mathbb R$. Hence, $t\mapsto A(t)$ is Lipschitz-continuous with respect to the Hausdorff metric. That was quite easy.

However, what I really would like to show is that $f : t\mapsto A(t)\cap B$ is continuous, where $B$ is a bounded, closed, and convex subset of $H$ and $f$ is defined on $K := \{t\in\mathbb R : A(t)\cap B\neq\emptyset\}$, which is a closed set.

I've tried a lot, but I can't seem to prove this. So, I'd be happy if anyone had an idea. For clarification: the Hausdorff distance between two sets $A,B\subset H$ is defined by
$$
d_H(A,B) := \max\left\{\sup_{a\in A}\operatorname{dist}(a,B),\,\sup_{b\in B}\operatorname{dist}(b,A)\right\}.
$$

Comment: Is $d_H(A(t),A(s)) = |t-s|$ really valid if $|v|\neq 1$? And don't you mean that "$f$ is only supported on $K$" where the support of a set-valued function is the part of the domain where $f \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: @md2perpe Yes,it should have been $\|v\|=1$, thx. Edited. But no, I meant "defined". Or how would you define $d_H(A,\emptyset)\,$?

Comment: The question of "defined" vs "supported" was about $f,$ not about $d_H$.

Comment: @md2perpe In fact, you're right. Thx. I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is almost yes. The function $f$ is continuous on the *interior* of the set of times such that it is non-empty.

Indeed, pick a reference point $x=(t_0 v+w)\in A(t_0)\cap B$, where $w\in v^{\perp}$, let $s<t_0$ and $t=\alpha s+(1-\alpha)t_0$ and observe $y=sv+w'\in f(s)$ where $w'\in v^{\perp}$. Then,
$$\alpha y+(1-\alpha)x=(\alpha s+(1-\alpha)t_0)v +\alpha w'+(1-\alpha)w,
$$
implying that $\alpha y+(1-\alpha)x\in A(t)$ and since $B$ is convex, we also get that $\alpha y+(1-\alpha)x\in f(t)$.

Hence, $$
d(y, f(t))\leq \|y-(\alpha y+(1-\alpha x))\|=(1-\alpha) \|y-x\|=(\frac{t-s}{t_0-s})\|x-y\|\leq \frac{t-s}{t_0-s} diam(B)
$$
Since this bound is uniform in $y$ we deduce that $\sup_{y\in f(s)}d(y,f(t))\leq \frac{t-s}{t_0-s} diam(B)$. Picking another reference point $z\in A(s_0)\cap B$ and running the argument backwards establishes
$$
d_H(f(t),f(s))\leq \max \left\{\frac{t-s}{t_0-s},\frac{t-s}{t-s_0} \right\} diam(B)
$$
for $t,s\in (s_0,t_0)$.

Unfortunately, continuity might fail at $t=\sup K$. Indeed, assume that $H$ is $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}_0)$ and let $v=v_0=(\delta^0_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ and $v_k:=(\delta^k_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}+(1-2^{-k})v_{0}$ for $k\geq 1$. Then, define $B$
$$
B:=\overline{conv} \{v_k|k\in \mathbb{N}_0\}
$$
Then, $B$ is closed, convex and bounded (it's contained in $B(0,3)$). We'll argue that $A(1)\cap B=\{v\}$. Having shown that, we'll just observe that $d(v_k, v)\geq 1$, proving that $d_H(A(1-2^{-k})\cap B,A(1) \cap B)\not \to 0$ as $t\to 1$.

So, indeed if $y\in A(1)\cap B$, then there exists $y_j=\sum_{k=0}^{N_j} \alpha_{k,j} v_k$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^{N_j}\alpha_{k,j}=1$, each $\alpha_{k,j}$ is positive and $y_j\to y$. Now, the $0$'th component of $y_j$ is at most
$$
(1-2^{-k_0})\alpha_{k_0,j}+\sum_{k\neq k_0} \alpha_{k,j}
$$
since the $0$'th component of $v_k$ is equal to $1-2^{-k}$. Since the $0$'th component of $y$ is equal to $1$, we get that $\alpha_{k,j}$ must go to $0$ for every $k\geq 1$.
Now, since $\alpha_{k,j}$ is equal to the $k$'th component of $y_j$ and the coordinate projections are continuous, we get that the $k$'th component of $y$ is $0$ for every $k\geq 1$. Thus, we get that $y=v$ and thus, that $A(1)\cap B=\{v\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, you show that the domain $K$ of the function $f$ is convex (hence it is a compact interval) and that $f$ is Lipschitz on compact sets in the interior of $K$. However, I think your counterexample is flawed because $A(1)\cap B\neq \{v\}$. As far as I understand, we have $v = v_0 = (1,0,0,\dots)$ and $v_1 = (\frac 32,\frac 12,0,\dots)$ and $A(1)$ is the set of sequences $(x_n)$ with $x_0=1$. So, definitely $v\in A(1)$, but also $\frac 12 v_0 + \frac 13v_1 = (1,\frac 16,0,\dots)\in A(1)$.

Comment: @Amsmath Hm... I suppose you're right. I do think the statement fails to be true at the end-point, though. I'll go back to thinking about it.

Comment: I still think that it's continuous at the endpoints. But let's see. Thanks so much for your collaboration.

Comment: @amsmath Wait... it was a typo, $v_1$ should be $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,...)$. Then, $v_2$ should be $(\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},0,...)$. So basically, the $0$'th component of the $v_k$ should all be strictly smaller than $1$ so that there for sure is no element in $A(1)\cap B$ which comes from a finite linear combination of the $v_k$'s.  I'll write up why $A(1)\cap B$ must be singleton $v$.

Comment: What is $k_0\,$? And the $0$'th component of $v_k$ is not $1-2^{-k}$ but $2^{-k}$.

Comment: $k_0$ is an arbitrary index. No. The $0$'th component of $v_k$ is $\sum_{j=1}^k 2^{-j}=1-2^{-(k+1)}$.

Comment: This is a really nice answer. Thank you! So, $f$ is locally Lipschitz on the interior of $K$, but might not even be continous at the two boundary points of $K$. Weird.

Comment: @amsmath Yeah, no sweat. One may note that the lack of continuity at the endpoints is inherently an infinite-dimensional phenomenon. It's also not clear to me that this isn't just a pathology due to a "bad" choice of reference vector $v$. For instance, one might ask whether, given $B$, there *exists* $v$ such that the corresponding $f$ is continuous on all of $K$. I mean... in my counter example, it seems to me like *any* other choice of unit reference vector would yield continuity at the end-point since the singularity is specifically built into the $0$'th canonical direction.